# Does a link with rel=noopener pass a referrer, or does it appear as direct traffic

Tags: tags, web-traffic

I want to know about `target="_blank" rel="noopener"` traffic channel resource. would be referral or Direct? If a user finds out the post in Google Search, What would it be Organic or Direct? I am a bit confused on using this and I was reading about it but there is no clarity on the `target="_blank" rel="noopener"`.

> I am pretty well aware about the `rel=noopener`, so kindly do not share the conventional definitions related to this.

Kindly share your thoughts on the same.

Comment: You may know what `rel=noopener` does but I had to look it up: https://jakearchibald.com/2016/performance-benefits-of-rel-noopener/

Comment: So you are asking if  `rel=noopener` hides the referrer causing traffic to appear as direct?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. Is there any resource because above one i am digging right now.

Comment: Why are you asking about Google Search?  Does Google use `rel=noopener`?

Comment: What if a user finds out a post using the tag in google search and click on the hyperlinks used in it. What would happen then?

Comment: Why would that matter?